# pfsense - OpenVPN no connection to local lan

Tags: openvpn, linux-networking, pfsense

I've configurded an pfsense to provide an OpenVPN server, but I can't access the local lan from the vpn client. I only dyn access the vpn server.

[The network configs of the vpnserver are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Lej.png)

[The firewall rules of the wan port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK6xr.png)

[The firewall rules of the lan port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Z5G.png)

[The firewall rules of the OpenVPN server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0S35.png)

Can you help me out with an hint? I'm unable to see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not clear whether your are doing a SITE to SITE VPN or a road warrior setup. Nevertheless, can you check the routing table on the client. If there is no route for the local LAN on the client side you can push routes from OpenVPN  server in the advance configuration tab e.g.
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.224.0";
It's sometimes required on Road warrior setups.